# "Reverse for '' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. "

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I applied the fixes in the stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842389/reverse-for-with-arguments-and-keyword-arguments-not-found):

```
<a href="{% url shop_index %}"><span>{% trans "Shop List" %}</span></a>
```

in `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^shop/$', 'index',  name="shop_index"),
```

But still the same error. Where am I wrong?

*UPDATE:*

---

`Django` **`1.5`**

`Python` **`2.7.2`**

`{% url shop_index %}` gives error. If I use `{% url 'shop_index' %}`, it is ok.

---

`Django` **`1.5.dev17865`**

`Python` **`2.7.3`**

`{% url 'shop_index' %}` gives error. If I use `{% url shop_index %}`, it is ok.

---

It is very strange.

Comment: Which Django version do you use?

Comment: Now I was trying in my cloud server. I deployed my project. Django versions are the same. But python versions are different. And in the server, it is giving same error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try putting `shop_index` in quotes:

```
<a href="{% url 'shop_index' %}">
```

Without the quotations, `shop_index` will be treated like a template variable instead of a string.