# Reverse for 'login' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

Tags: python, django

I want to use reverse() in my Django view to avoid hard code, but get "**Reverse for 'login' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found**".  Here is my code:

URLConf:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^accounts/', include('accounts.urls', namespace="accounts")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^login/$', views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^signup/$', views.signup, name='signup'),
)
```

views.py:

```
def login(request):
    return render(request, reverse("login"))


def signup(request):
    return render(request, reverse("signup"))
```

Here is my traceback info:

> Environment:
>
> Request Method: GET
>   Request URL: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/`
>
> Django Version: 1.7
>   Python Version: 2.7.5
>   Installed Applications:
>   ('django.contrib.admin',
>   'django.contrib.auth',
>   'django.contrib.contenttypes',
>   'django.contrib.sessions',
>   'django.contrib.messages',
>   'django.contrib.staticfiles',
>   'accounts')
>   Installed Middleware:
>   ('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
>   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
>   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
>   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
>   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')
>
> Traceback:
>   File "/Users/feizhao/.virtualenvs/nahan/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
>     111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>   File "/Users/feizhao/dropbox/nahan/accounts/views.py" in login
>     11.     return render(request, reverse("login"))
>   File "/Users/feizhao/.virtualenvs/nahan/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
>     546.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
>   File "/Users/feizhao/.virtualenvs/nahan/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
>     463.                              (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))
>
> Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /accounts/login/
>   Exception Value: Reverse for 'login' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

I've seen some similar question in stackoverflow already, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11383534/reverse-for-with-arguments-and-keyword-arguments-not-found), but no help.

Anyone can tell me why it's wrong?  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've given the urls a namespace so you need to include that in the name that you're reversing:

```
def login(request):
    return render(request, reverse("accounts:login"))


def signup(request):
    return render(request, reverse("accounts:signup"))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get "TemplateDoesNotExist at /accounts/login/
". My template is accounts/templates/accounts/
login.html, accounts/templates/accounts/signup.html.

Comment: that's a separate question, but I think probably the dir structure should be `accounts/templates/signup.html` ...see docs for django `TEMPLATE_DIRS` and `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader

Comment: I change the dir structure to accounts/templates/signup.html , still no work.

Comment: Get it! thanks very much, silly question! Read the docs and think it through! Thanks again.