# Frustrating NoReverseMatch Found

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm having a tough time debugging this particular error. I have the following in my `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^report/(?P<share_url>\w+)/$', 'share', 
  name='share'),
url(r'^report/(?P<share_url>\w+)/revoke/$', 'share_revoke',
  name='share_revoke'),
```

In `views.py` I have:

```
def share(request, share_url):
  ...

@login_required
def share_revoke(request, share_url):
  ...
```

In my template I have:

```
<a href='{% url share share_url %}'>Share</a>
<a href='{% url share_revoke share_url %}'>Revoke</a>
```

When I try and load this template, I get a `NoReverseMatch`:

> ### NoReverseMatch at /mypath/
>
> Reverse for 'share_revoke' with arguments '(u'Sh4rE',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Why is it failing for the second url and not the first? I am logged in.

Trying this on the shell:

```
>>> reverse('share',args=(u'klajsdf',))
'/report/klajsdf/'

>>> reverse('share_revoke',args=(u'klajsdf',))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ubuntu/virt/virt1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 476, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/ubuntu/virt/virt1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 396, in _reverse_with_prefix
    "arguments '%s' not found." % (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs))
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'share_revoke' with arguments '(u'klajsdf',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

Comment: Try this SO question and answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842389/reverse-for-with-arguments-and-keyword-arguments-not-found

Comment: validate that share_revoke share_url contains the right data

Comment: @RickardZachrisson It does.

Comment: You mean `'share'` instead of `'share_url'` actually in `reverse('share_url',args=(u'klajsdf',))`?

Comment: @okm yes I do, good spot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a non-issue in the end. My problem was SublimeText2 SFTP had got confused and wasn't overwriting the `urls.py` on my server, hence the large amount of wtf.