# django noreversematch error when passing arguments

Tags: django

I am getting an error NoReverseMatch at /user/login/ when i click on the page /users/login.
Below is how my code looks

urls.py

```
  url(r'^$', 'views.homepage', name='home'),
  url(r'^user/login/$', 'coolstuff.views.login_view'),
```

views.py

```
def login_view(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
      username = request.POST['email']
      password = request.POST['password']
      user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
      if user is not None and user.is_active:
         login(request, user)
         return HttpResponseRedirect(request.GET.get("next"))
      else:
          login_error = "Your username and/or password are incorrect."
          return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('views.homepage', kwargs={'login_error': login_error}))


def homepage(request, login_error=''):
    return render_to_response(homepage.html,
         {'login_error': login_error,},
         context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

So, i want to pass the login_error variable only when the user types in wrong username or password. In any other case, the homepage gets called with no login_error.
I am trying to pass login_error as an extra variable into the view function but getting the error NoReverseMatch at /user/login/.

How can i solve this ?

Comment: What version of Django are you using?

Comment: i am using django 1.5

Comment: Can you post your template `homepage.html`?

Comment: Have you checked this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842389/reverse-for-with-arguments-and-keyword-arguments-not-found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view doesn't take any arguments in the url pattern which is why it is failing. You need to use the [messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/) which is designed for this use case.