# How to use reverse() from django.core.urlresolvers.reverse

Tags: django, debugging

How do you use the `reverse()` from `django.core.urlresolvers.reverse` at the command line? I want to debug what is going wrong in my Django application. I am not sure if it is happening at the `views`, the `urls` or the `html` template page.

I have the command line open in the directory of the project, but it doesn't recognize my commands (which I am borrowing from the Django-Project page).

Comment: What do you mean, "doesn't recognize my commands"? What happens? What output do you see? How did you start the shell in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `urls.py` file consists on something like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'views.recent', name='recent'),
    url(r'^recent/(?P<page>\d+)$', 'views.recent', name='recent')
)
```

using `python manage.py shell` in your project directory you do the following:

```
>>> from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
>>> reverse('recent')
'/recent'
```

you can pass specific parameters passing a list as `args` or a dictionary as `kwargs`

```
>>> reverse('recent', args=[1])
'/recent/1'
>>> reverse('recent', kwargs={'page': 2})
'/recent/2'
```

check the [doc on reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/) for your particular version of Django.

Comment: In >= year 2019 use `from django.urls import reverse`