# Reverse for ‘<a_view>' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'id': None}' not found

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I get stuck on a « NoReverseMatch » exception with a reverse.

**Reverse for 'notifications_read' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'id': None}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['notifications/read/(?P\d+)/$']**

I’m trying to check when notifications are read on comments. Basically, I’ve got this so far:

**url.py:**

```
url(r'^notifications/read/(?P<id>\d+)/$', notifications.views.read, name='notifications_read')
```

And the problem seems to occur in the class Notification, in the **str**(self) method of:

**notifications/models.py**

```
context = {
    "sender": self.sender_object,
    "verb": self.verb,
    "target": self.target_object,
    "action": self.action_object,
    "verified_read": reverse('notifications_read', kwargs={"id": self.id}),
    "target_url": target_url,
}
return "{sender} {verb} <a href='{verified_read}?next={target_url}'>{target}</a> with {action}.".format(**context)
```

I can’t figure out **why self.id is None which seems to be the problem**, since when I take it off in the URL pattern, as well as the kwargs in the reverse, I don’t get the exception (but neither the needed URL).

If I put str(self.id) as:

```
reverse('notifications_read', kwargs={'id': str(self.id)})
```

with

```
url(r'^notifications/read/(?P<id>[\w-]+)/$', notifications.views.read, name='notifications_read')
```

there is **no exception but the rendering is /notifications/read/None/**

I know there are lots of similar questions out there like [Reverse for '*' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842389/reverse-for-with-arguments-and-keyword-arguments-not-found)

But in none of them, there seem to be this problem with self.id returning None.

I’m using **Django 1.9.2 with python 3.5**

Could you help? It would be really appreciated.
***Thanks a lot!***

If it can be helpful, the exception is also not occurring when I comment those lines:

In **comments/views.py**

```
notify.send(
    request.user,
    action=new_comment,
    target=parent_comment,
    recipient=parent_comment.user,
    verb="replied to"
)
```

And here is the corresponding view in **notifications/views.py**:

```
@login_required
def read(request, id):
    try:
        next = request.GET.get('next', None)
        notifications = Notification.objects.get(id=id)
        if notifications.recipient == request.user:
            notifications.read = True
            notifications.save()
            if next is not None:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(next)
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("notifications_all"))
        else:
            raise Http404
    except:
        raise HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("notifications_all"))
```

On the **debug page**, I get:

```
Request Method: POST

Request URL: http://0.0.0.0:8000/comment/create/

Django Version: 1.9.2

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch

Exception Value: Reverse for 'notifications_read' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'id': None}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['notifications/read/(?P<id>\\d+)/$']

Exception Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 508

Python Executable:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3

Python Version:3.5.0
```

**EDIT 2 (full Traceback):**

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://0.0.0.0:8000/comment/create/

Django Version: 1.9.2
Python Version: 3.5.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'crispy_forms',
 'accounts',
 'comments',
 'notifications',
 'videos']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/leomaltrait/PycharmProjects/srvup/src/comments/views.py" in comment_create_view
  80.                     verb="commented on"

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py" in send
  192.             response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)

File "/Users/leomaltrait/PycharmProjects/srvup/src/notifications/models.py" in new_notification
  157.     print(new_note)

File "/Users/leomaltrait/PycharmProjects/srvup/src/notifications/models.py" in __str__
  95.             "verified_read": reverse('notifications_read', kwargs={"id": self.id}),

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  600.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  508.                              (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /comment/create/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'notifications_read' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'id': None}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['notifications/read/(?P<id>\\d+)/$']
```

Comment: Where in your models is the `context = ...` code block? Can you show your full model?

Comment: The error is occuring on the url `http://0.0.0.0:8000/comment/create/`. You don't appear to have shown the view for that url.

Comment: Looks like the `object` has not been created yet. So it has no `id`

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I edited the question (after EDIT at the bottom of the question) with the full model and the view corresponding to /comment/create/. I wanted to put as little as possible for you not to have to much info, but it seems it wasn't enough (I'm kind of a newbie)

Comment: Is that the full traceback from the debug page?

Comment: It wasn't, I'm really sorry. I just put it after the EDIT 2 at the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the problem. It was the print statement that we can see in the **Traceback: print(new_note)**. It was part of another method (new_notification).

I didn't even know a print could cause exceptions. Especially since the new_note object seems to exist (the notification are working well without this print statement).

Anyway, thanks a lot for your time and help guys!