# Reverse for '' with keyword arguments '' not found

Tags: django, python-3.x, url

I'm using `django 2.1` and `python 3.6` and I'm running to an issue which seems like [other people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842389/reverse-for-with-arguments-and-keyword-arguments-not-found) have ran into in past years.

This is part of my `views.py`:

```
def blog_list_by_cat(request, cat_id, cat_name):
    ...

def blog_list_by_genre(request, genre_id, genre_name):
    ...
```

This is my `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    re_path(r'^blog/(?P<blog_id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[^/]+)/?$', views.single_blog, name='single_blog'),
    re_path(r'^blog-list/(?P<cat_id>\d+)/(?P<cat_name>[^/]+)/?$', views.blog_list_by_cat, name='blog_list_by_cat'),
    path('blog-list/latest/', views.blog_latest, name='blog_latest'),
    re_path(r'^blog-list/genre/(?P<genre_id>\d+)/(?P<genre_name>[^/]+)/?$', views.blog_list_by_genre, name='blog_list_by_genre'),
]
```

and in my template when I call those links, this one works fine:

```
{% for cat in cat_list %}
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'blog_list_by_cat' cat_id=cat.id cat_name=cat.cat %}">{{ cat.cat }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

While this one throw an error in the same template:

```
{% for genre in genre_list %}
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'blog_list_by_genre' genre_id=genre.id genre_name=genre.title %}">{{ genre.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

This is the full error:

> Exception Type:   NoReverseMatch
>
> Exception Value: Reverse for 'blog_list_by_genre' with keyword arguments '{'genre_id':
>   5, 'genre_name': 'Action'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
>   ['blog-list/genre/(?P\d+)/(?P[^/]+)/?$']

As you can see, I'm using [named urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns) and I'm using quotations around the url name and not adding app name in urls. both codes are the same. But why the second one does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a non-greedy qualifier:

```
(?P<genre_name>.+?)
```

Sometimes this helps me match urls when the name of my model has a space in it like "Space Needle".

Comment: Thank you. it solved the issue. But now I got same error for next url. Plz check it out!

Comment: @AlexJolig - Please also post your html link.

Comment: Error is the same. I've included it.

Comment: Looks like the template is not being passed a genre_name.

Comment: @AlexJolig - ah try genre_name=cgenre.title *in the template link.

Comment: Just missing a 'c' I think.

Comment: Ops! that was a silly mistake. I'll remove the update part of the answer. Thank you. It's all fine now